# Powershell function to accept Uri with & character

Tags: string, powershell, function, uri

how should I provide to powershell function Uri string with & character, like Get-ValidUri -Uri https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZ382nYZPPg&t=421s it always returns error where 'The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.' I can provide it with double quotes like Get-ValidUri -Uri "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZ382nYZPPg&t=421s" then it works... Thanks in advance !

function Get-WebLinkValid
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[ValidateScript({ ({ "{0}" } -f $TestUri).Trim() })]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[System.UriFormat]$TestUri
)

```
[System.Uri]$Uri = ({ "{0}" } -f $TestUri).Trim()
```

## script

}

Comment: `[uri]::EscapeDataString('&')`

Comment: Thanks, but where to put this one ?

Comment: You can encode your uri to handle special characters. You should clarify what your exact issue is. Your post is poorly formatted and your question unclear.

Comment: Okay, simply: function Get-Something
{
 [CmdletBinding()]
 param
 (
  [uri]$aaa
 )
 
 #TODO: Place script here
} When you pass the parameter like Get-Something efrewfe&erwrew it returns an error.

Comment: @IvanBenishek - long story short, in Windows PowerShell 5.1, ```&``` is not allowed in "BareWord" tokens (i.e. unquoted strings). You need to wrap it in double-quotes to make it a "DoubleQuoted" token, and then you can use special characters like ```&```, ```space```, etc, as part of the string value. Try this on the command line to see how PowerShell parses the script source: ```{ Get-Something efrewfe }.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements[1]``` and then quote the string and try again...

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: In short: arguments that contains _spaces_ and/or other metacharacters such as `&` must be _quoted_, e.g, `'Program Files'`). See the linked duplicate for details.